# str_replace() in DOM

Tags: php, html, dom

My current code

```
 $this->data = $this->result->RetrieveDocumentResult;

        $this->dom = new DOMDocument();
        $this->dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
        $this->dom->formatOutput = true;
        $this->dom->loadHTML(base64_decode($this->data));

        $exceptions = array(
            'a'   => array('href'),
            'img' => array('src')
        );

        $this->stripAttributes($exceptions);
        $this->stripSpanTags();


        file_put_contents('Recode/' . $flname . '.html', base64_decode($this->data));
    }

    public function stripAttributes(array $exceptions)
    {
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($this->dom);
        if (false === ($elements = $xpath->query("//*"))) die('Xpath error!');

        /** @var $element DOMElement */
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            for ($i = $element->attributes->length; --$i >= 0;) {
                $this->tag       = $element->nodeName;
                $this->attribute = $element->attributes->item($i)->nodeName;

                if ($this->checkAttrExceptions($exceptions)) continue;

                $element->removeAttribute($this->attribute);
            }
        }

        $this->data = base64_encode($this->dom->saveHTML());
    }

    public function checkAttrExceptions(array $exceptions)
    {
        foreach ($exceptions as $tag => $attributes) {
            if (empty($attributes) || !is_array($attributes)) {
                die('Attributes not set!');
            }

            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                if ($tag === $this->tag && $attribute === $this->attribute) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Strip SPAN tags from current DOM document
     *
     * @return void
     */
    /**
     * Strip SPAN tags from current DOM document
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function stripSpanTags ()
    {
        $nodes = $this->dom->getElementsByTagName('span');

        while ($span = $nodes->item(0)) {
            $replacement = $this->dom->createDocumentFragment();
            while ($inner = $span->childNodes->item(0)) {
                $replacement->appendChild($inner);
            }
            $span->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement, $span);
        }
       $this->data = base64_encode($this->dom->saveHTML());

    }


}
```

Want to remove all `&nbsp;` in HTML did the following

```
$html = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $html);
```

But confused how and where to add this to the first set of codes .. Help me please

Also this should not override previous tag filters in first set of codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution ., The following code works

```
$this->result = $this->soap->RetrieveDocument(
            array('format' => 'html')
        );

        $this->data = $this->result->RetrieveDocumentResult;

        $this->dom = new DOMDocument();
        $this->dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
        $this->dom->formatOutput = true;
        $this->dom->loadHTML(base64_decode($this->data));

        $exceptions = array(
            'a'   => array('href'),
            'img' => array('src')
        );

        $this->stripAttributes($exceptions);
        $this->stripSpanTags();

        $decoded = base64_decode($this->data);
        $decoded = $this->stripNonBreakingSpaces($decoded);

        file_put_contents('Recode/' . $flname . '.html', $decoded);
    }

    public function stripAttributes(array $exceptions)
    {
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($this->dom);
        if (false === ($elements = $xpath->query("//*"))) die('Xpath error!');

        /** @var $element DOMElement */
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            for ($i = $element->attributes->length; --$i >= 0;) {
                $this->tag       = $element->nodeName;
                $this->attribute = $element->attributes->item($i)->nodeName;

                if ($this->checkAttrExceptions($exceptions)) continue;

                $element->removeAttribute($this->attribute);
            }
        }

        $this->data = base64_encode($this->dom->saveHTML());
    }

    public function checkAttrExceptions(array $exceptions)
    {
        foreach ($exceptions as $tag => $attributes) {
            if (empty($attributes) || !is_array($attributes)) {
                die('Attributes not set!');
            }

            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                if ($tag === $this->tag && $attribute === $this->attribute) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Strip SPAN tags from current DOM document
     *
     * @return void
     */
    /**
     * Strip SPAN tags from current DOM document
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function stripSpanTags ()
    {
        $nodes = $this->dom->getElementsByTagName('span');

        while ($span = $nodes->item(0)) {
            $replacement = $this->dom->createDocumentFragment();
            while ($inner = $span->childNodes->item(0)) {
                $replacement->appendChild($inner);
            }
            $span->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement, $span);
        }

        $this->data = base64_encode($this->dom->saveHTML());
    }


    /**
     * Replace all &nbsp; entities within a string with a regular space
     *
     * @param string $string Input string
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function stripNonBreakingSpaces ($string)
    {
        return str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $string);
    }


}
```